# Formulário com API da Tabela FIPE utilizando Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, api

Fala pessoal.
Sou iniciante em Angular e gostaria de uma ajuda com esse formulário.

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>

    <title>Teste</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script>

        angular.module('app', []);
        angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($http, $scope){

            $http.get('https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas').success(function(data) {
                $scope.greeting = data;
            });

            $scope.carregarModelo = function (modelo) {
                $http.get("https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas/"+modelo+"/modelos").success(function (data) {
                   $scope.modelo = data;
                });
            };

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>
        <h1>Marcas</h1>
        <select id="teste1" class="customSel">
            <option ng-click="carregarModelo({{ x.codigo }})" ng-repeat="x in greeting" value="{{ x.codigo }}">{{ x.nome }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Modelo</h1>
        <select id="teste2" class="customSel">
            <option value="0" selected>Selecione</option>
            <option ng-repeat="x in modelo" value="{{ x.codigo }}">{{ x.nome }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

Eu estou tentando criar um form que consulta qual a marca de carro selecionada e depois fornece o nome dos carros referentes a essa marca.

A parte de consultar a marca já funciona, eu não consegui fazer funcionar a lista dos carros, pois não estou conseguindo repassar o value da marca para uma nova função, poderiam me ajudar? Valeu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue solução no plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/fRyU7lbbwy0EVcqQCCxQ

Alterei para utilizar o "ng-options" na marca e utilizei o "ng-change" para disparar a consulta dos modelos.

```
<script>

    angular.module('app', []);
    angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($http, $scope){

        $http.get('https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas').success(function(data) {
            $scope.greeting = data;
        });

        $scope.carregarModelo = function (marca) {
            $http.get("https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas/"+marca.codigo+"/modelos").success(function (data) {
               $scope.modelo = data;
            });
        };

    });
</script>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div>
    <h1>Marcas</h1>
    <select id="teste1" class="customSel" ng-options="x as x.nome for x in greeting" ng-model="marca" ng-change="carregarModelo(marca)">
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Modelo</h1>
    <select id="teste2" class="customSel">
        <option value="0" selected>Selecione</option>
        <option ng-repeat="x in modelo.modelos" value="{{ x.codigo }}">{{ x.nome }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, porém minha dúvida está em como eu vou trazer os dados da segunda requisição pegando o ID da marca para retornar os modelos. Editei o post pra deixar mais explicito, obrigado pela contribuição.

Comment: Entendi. Alterei minha resposta. Veja se te ajuda agora. A principio funcionou aqui.

Comment: Deu certo Alexandre, valeu.